# mysql keeps lossing user permisions

Tags: linux, mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mysql5.5

We have a mysql database on ubuntu 14.04 server. It was working really fine for months until some weeks ago, when it started with this thing. It suddenly losses all user permisions and we have to set all of them again. We to the folowing commands (with root permisions):

```
service mysql stop
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

then in mysql client:

```
flush privileges;
grant [privileges] on dbname.tblname to "user"@"host" identified by "password"; (for every user)
flush privileges;
```

then we stop mysqld_safe and start mysql normally again.

I would need to know which logs to activate and some clue about why is this happening. 
mysql version is 5.5.44

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using replication? Have you forgotten to exclude the `mysql` database from replication?

Comment: Just one mysql server, no replication.

Comment: You may need to log all statements to find out whose causing this. It's not something that MySQL does normally... this may cause *a lot* of logging. BTW: note that the `flush privileges` is not necessary in the case you show; it's only useful if you directly manipulate the mysql.* tables.

Comment: I'll turn query logs on and see what happens. Thanks for the reply.